# MATLAB store value of looping to table form

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have the following working code which display parameter count after each hour. The code use two function. Basically my code does

- User run test_main(hour, total parameter)
- test_main generate random number
- test_main send number to test_sub
- test_sub respond to the number

test_main function

```
 function[] = test_main(x, pc)

for i = 1:x %loop for time
    fprintf('\n Time is %d hour after count start .  \n', i);

    for t = 1:pc
        fprintf('\nPARAMETER at test main %d ', t);

        w=rand; %random error generator. 
        if w<0.5 
            status=1;
        else
            status=99; 
        end

    % fprintf('\n Time is %d hour after count start .  \n', i);

    test_sub(status);
    end  
end
end
```

test_sub function

```
function[a] = test_sub(z)

%fprintf('\nPARAMETER inside test sub %d ', count)
fprintf('\n Value is %d \n', z);

    if (z==1) %if input equal to 0
     j=1; %store temporary value to j
     a=j; 
     disp('new value is 1')

    elseif (z==99)
     j=1;
     a=j;
     disp('new value is 100')
else
disp('unidentified error')
end
end
```

I notice that i haven't send a value back from test_sub to test_main. Im not sure how to record the value after each loop into table form. I need the table looks like:

```
         Parameter 1    Parameter 2   ..... parameter N
Time 1        1             100
Time 2       100             1
....
Time N
```

Can the parameter and time expand according to the value that user insert at the test_main function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i am not quite sure what the function does, but creating the table you want might be enough. i am assuming x and pc are just numbers and you have no name for each parameter . I would create a cell array first then transform it into a table:

```
    function [output] = test_main(x, pc) %this functions output would be the table you want
   cell_array=cell(x,pc+1); %creating a cellarray first
   names=cell(1,pc+1);
   names{1,1}='Time';
    for i = 1:x %loop for time
        fprintf('\n Time is %d hour after count start .  \n', i);
        cell_array{i,1}=i;

        for t = 1:pc
            fprintf('\nPARAMETER at test main %d ', t);

            w=rand; %random error generator. 
            if w<0.5 
                status=1;
            else
                status=99; 
            end

        % fprintf('\n Time is %d hour after count start .  \n', i);

        cell_array{i,t+1}=test_sub(status); %writing in row i at column t the value of test_sub
        names{1,t+1}=['Parameter_' num2str(t)];
        end  
    end

    output=cell2table(cell_array,'VariableNames',names); %transforming it into a table

 end
```

in the test_sub you write on both cases of the if 'a=1' i feel like the second should be a 100. The output looks like your example but the parameternames arent changed to 'Parameter X'. you can do that in the cell2table if you want

Comment: how can i display the time beside the cell_array?

Comment: when i change the cell_array, the time column also change. can it be like time_array cell_array1 cell_array2 ?

Comment: what do you change in the cell_array? do you only want different names on the top?

Comment: yes. different names on top. the current code i run will give me cell_array1 cell_array2 cell_array3. can i change it to time parameter1 paramter2?

Comment: i edited the answer. if you wqant to work more with tables in matlab please look up the table function ('help table' in command window) and look at the table properties of your current table ('output.Properties' in command window